# Arduino and ATtiny84 w/RF

Tags: attiny, rf

I'm trying to send data from an ATtiny84 [1mhz] to Arduino Uno using a 433Mhz rf module and Manchester lib.
Now I came across a weird problem, no matter what value I transmit, When I receive it on the arduino and to the Serial monitor, it always shows value of 806,No matter what I have really transmitted.

ATtiny side

```
void setup()
{
  man.workAround1MhzTinyCore(); //add this in order for transmitter to work with 1Mhz Attiny85/84
  man.setupTransmit(transmit_pin, MAN_1200);
}

// And how I transmit
// RGBread is int, I also tried man.transmit((uint16_t)RGBread[i]); same result.
  for(int i=0; i<3; i++)
  {
    man.transmit(RGBread[i]);
  }
```

Uno

```
void setup()
{
  man.setupReceive(reciever_pin, MAN_1200);
  man.beginReceive();
}

  if (man.receiveComplete()) {
    Serial.println(man.getMessage());
    man.beginReceive(); //start listening for next message right after you retrieve the message
  }
```

Thanks to all helpers.

Comment: As a test, make your transmit value explicitly count in a loop to rule out problems with the ultimate data source.  Are you sure that man.getMessage() returns something meaningful for printing?  If you don't have a scope to validate the received data waveform, you could try substituting a direct connection for the RF modules.

Comment: The values are analogRead's returns.

Comment: I did tried to put my own inputs instead of that analogRead, 0 125 and 255 low mid and high, same results its all 806 on the reciever side.

Comment: Either substitute a direct connection for the RF modules and test that, or see if you can use a PC soundcard as a crude scope to examine the transmitted and received data signals.

Comment: Check what? And if you connect the reciever directly to a led, you can see it blinking all the time, lots of interference, but that's okay. You get what you paid for ;)- Thought it's the lib's job to make the link work right?

Comment: The library can't do anything unless there is signal in the noise, something you've yet to prove.  I'm still recommending you try a direct connection to verify that the transmitter and receiver are working, and at the same settings.